# Soap request with strong-soap

Tags: node.js, web-services, soap

I'm using strong-soap node module to do soap requests to get information. 
I'm requesting info from a soap server. The soap request works perfectly fine but its the structure of the js Object that creates the xml request that I'm having trouble with, the js object below...

```
var requestArgs = {
   authUserName: 'user',
   authPassword: 'pass',
   username: 'user',
   requestedValues: {
      string: 'userid',
      string: 'Email',
      string: 'DisplayName'
   }
};
```

When I send the request it seems that the result is only returning the last index of the obj in requestedValues (DisplayName), It does not seem to run through the obj when making the xml request. Now I don't think I'm structuring the js object correctly. I have tried a few ways eg below:

```
requestedValues: [{string: 'useid'}, {string: 'Email'}]
```

Comment: Hi, have you found your solution? I've encountered similar problem

Comment: I had to restructure my json object. I don't have the code I used anymore... But how are you structuring your json object?